# C++ free(): invalid pointer abortado ao tentar criar uma função

Tags: c++, loop, memória, vector

Estou tentando criar uma biblioteca para operações com matrizes no C++ mas estou esbarrando em um problema.

Eu criei uma função para imprimir na tela uma determinada matriz. A função até retorna os valores esperados, contudo, na ultima linha aparece a seguinte mensagem de erro:

```
free(): invalid pointer
Abortado Abortado (imagem do núcleo gravada)
```

Segue abaixo o código:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

vector<vector<double>> imprime(vector<vector<double>> X) {

    int linhas  = X.size();
    int colunas = X[0].size();

    for (int i=0; i<linhas; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<colunas; j++) {
            cout << X[i][j] << "\t";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

int main() {

vector<vector<double>> X {
        {1.0, 2.0, 3.0,2.5},
        {2.0, 5.0,-1.0,2.0},
        {-1.5,2.7,3.3,-0.8}
};

imprime(X);

return 0;
}
```

Quando eu tento fazer o laço for direto na função main, ele funciona:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {

vector<vector<double>> X {
        {1.0, 2.0, 3.0,2.5},
        {2.0, 5.0,-1.0,2.0},
        {-1.5,2.7,3.3,-0.8}
};

for (int i=0; i<X.size(); i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<X[0].size(); j++) {
            cout << X[i][j] << "\t";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Na função `vector<vector<double>> imprime(vector<vector<double>> X) {` não faltou um return? Aliás  não poderia ser void?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você não está retornando alguma coisa, então não tem porque ter um tipo de retorno ali.

Se fosse retornar, o que não é necessário no código apresentado, aí teria que ter um `return` no código.

Existe um erro conceitual aí que funciona nesse caso mas nada garante que todas as colunas terão o mesmo tamanho, então pegar o tamanho individual é um erro que não é a causa do problema demostrando.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

void imprime(vector<vector<double>> X) {
    int linhas  = X.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < linhas; i++) {
        int colunas = X[0].size();
        for (int j = 0; j < colunas; j++) cout << X[i][j] << "\t";
        cout << endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    vector<vector<double>> X {
            {1.0, 2.0, 3.0,2.5},
            {2.0, 5.0,-1.0,2.0},
            {-1.5,2.7,3.3,-0.8}
    };
    imprime(X);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/9V69wm). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/rbixhiuq-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Function/VoidReturn.cpp).

Comment: Nossa, que vacilo que eu dei! Era exatamente esse o problema, agora está funcionando certo. Muito obrigado! :)